# Why my Tailwind classes have stopped working

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I started using Tailwind for the first time and I'm only using it with JavaScript for now. The first day the classes were working fine and everything, but when I opened my project on VSCode the next day, the only Tailwind classes that are still working are the ones that I have added previously. If I try to add more classes and design into my HTML nothing happens.

For instance when I added `text-3xl` to the h2 tag, the text font size doesn't change. Also, if I add a new color to my text or add a background color it doesn't take effect.

**[Link to all my code and files in Github](https://github.com/IssamAth/manage-landing-page)**

```
<div class="flex flex-col md:w-1/2">
  <h2 class="text-center text-3xl font-bold md:text-left">Track company-wide progress</h1>
  <p class="text-center md:text-left mt-4 mb-6">See how your day-to-day tasks fit into the wider vision. Go from tracking progress at the milestone level all the way done to the smallest of details. Never lose sight of the bigger picture again.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tailwind does not include all of its utility classes in the output CSS file. Instead, it parses out the classes you are using in your code when you run the build process and only adds those to the output file.

So, if you are adding classes to your code, you will have to rerun the build, either manually or by including the `--watch` option in your build command. For example:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

Note: this is also why adding previously unused utility classes in your browser dev tools' DOM inspector will not immediately affect elements on your page.

Comment: Finally an appropriate answer to my question! Thank you man, I appreciate that.